# Custom PCB with ADC for monitoring Lifepo4 battery bank voltages

Tags: pcb, adc, raspberry-pi, python

I designed a custom PCB board to allow me to monitor the individual battery cell voltages in my Lifepo4 48v battery bank.

Here is a schematic of the PCB:
[image]

Basically I'm using a molex micro fit junior connector to get leads from each of the battery cells positive terminal, each lead gets connected to 1 of 2 high voltage 8 channel multiplexer's, the output of the mulitplexers goes through a voltage divider then to A0 of the ADS1115.

I'm using this as a hat for a raspberry pi 4

there are 2 voltage regulators - 1 that outputs 5v for the pi and ADS1115 and 1 that outputs 15v for the mux

The problem I am running into is when I run the following program to monitor voltage and set the corresponding gpio pins high for any of the cells, I get the same reading (~0.116v - ~0.119v) no matter what channel the mux is on. When the mux is set to low, I get 0v as expected.

Here is the program I'm using to monitor voltage for the ADS1115:

```py
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)
#ads.gain = 16

chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

print("{:>5}\t{:>5}".format('raw', 'v'))

while True:
    print("{:>5}\t{:>5.3f}".format(chan.value, chan.voltage))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I've tried adding a 10k pull-up resistor from scl to 3.3v on the pi header as well as sda but am getting the same results.

I'm super stumped here and would appreciate any help on this one!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, I am just curious - why are you using single ended measurement? You have all the wires you need and ADC supports differential input. If you use one MUX for odd, another for even then you can have much better precision.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way to go about this than what I came up with, I need to get something working first and then I can improve upon it from there. In my POC testing I verified that the circuit setup with an ADS1115 breakout and the same voltage divider provided the 10mv accuracy I needed which is why I went with this design

Comment: The mux has an ON-resistance of 2 kOhms which is rather inaccurate and temperature dependent so it will screw the accuracy of the voltage divider. Also it cannot switch voltage that is higher than its own power supply, which is 15V in youy case. It has good overvoltage protection, so it should survive, but it won't work.

Comment: that doesn't explain why I can't read any voltages though, even the voltages that are under 15v all show as the same which I think points to a separate issue?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the cells in your schematic so we know exactly what these B0-x pins connect to. Also indicate what readings you would expect.

Comment: But indeed agree with @NomNomCameron, that design cannot work. Page 8 of the datasheet: *the multiplexer’s output swing is limited to about -12V to +13.5V with  ±15V supplies*.

Comment: The MAX14921 would be a suitable multiplexer that's designed specifically for this application. Or you can keep things simple and use 16 voltage dividers and 4x ADS1115 (this will be less accurate though, even with high precision resistors), without multiplexing.

Comment: The "Bx-x" flags go to positive leads from each lifepo4 battery cell (16s)

The readings I am expecting will be anywhere from ~0.2v - ~3v (the individual cell voltages run through the voltage divider)

I'm not sure I follow what the "output swing" means that you're citing? The datasheet shows an operational voltage that is within what I'll be using it for? How would it be rated for 60+v and only be able to pass 1/4 of that through?

Comment: The battery management IC that you linked is very interesting. I didn't know those were manufacturered. I'm having a hard time fully understanding how they work though. Is the basic idea connecting each positive lead from my cells to the corresponding pins on the chip, along with ground and then grabbing the voltage values from the chip through i2c? Is there any documentation you're aware of of someone using this with an arduino or raspberry pi?

Comment: @NomNomCameron "How would it be rated for 60+v" That is "fault input voltage", which is a voltage that does not damage the chip when applied. It does not mean it will be passed to the output. From datasheet: "The MAX378 limits the output voltage to about 1.5V below V+ and about 3V above V-"

Comment: Would this mux work instead of what I'm currently using?

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX14752-MAX14753-1515255.pdf

on the data sheet I see that the maximum analog range is Vdd, if I connected the main positive and negative to vdd and vss respetively would I be able to pass through the 2.5v-58v I need through the mux?